# Accessing XSLT param and variable values from lxml extension elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

I would like to access `xsl:param` and `xsl:variable` values from XSLT extension-elements in lxml, something like:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:abc="bar"
    extension-element-prefixes="abc">
    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:param name="param1">default param value</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- var1 is unnecessary - it's purely for demonstration -->
        <xsl:variable name="var1" select="$param1"/>
        <abc:foo attr1="{$var1}"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat( 'XSLT ouput: ', $var1 )"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```py
    #!/usr/local/bin/python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    
    import sys
    
    from lxml import etree
    from copy import deepcopy
    
    class FooExtensionElement( etree.XSLTExtension ):
    
        def execute( self, context, self_node, input_node, output_parent ):
            attr1 = self_node.get( "attr1" )
            print( "attr1: {}".format( attr1 ))
    
    
    parser = etree.XMLParser( load_dtd=True )
    extensions = { 
        ( 'bar', 'foo' ) : FooExtensionElement()
    }
    transformer = etree.XSLT( etree.parse( sys.stdin, parser ), extensions = extensions )
    xml_doc = etree.XML( '<dummy/>' )
    result = transformer( xml_doc, param1=etree.XSLT.strparam( "passed param value" ))
    print( result )
```

The output of this is:

```
attr1: $var1
XSLT ouput: passed param value
```

What I would like to do is set some simple (string) values in `xsl:variable`s (or pass them in to `xsl:param` as above) and then be able to use their `$variable` values within my extension-elements.
In the example above, `attr1` in the `FooExtensionElement` would be assigned value "passed param value".

`xsl:variable` and `xsl:param` are operating in an entirely different namespace to `abc:foo`.  Because of this namespace mismatch, I don't expect the XSLT to pass the *value* of `$var1` to `abc:foo/@attr1`.

**Possible solution 1**:
The transformer must maintain a map of `xsl:variable/@name|xsl:param/@name` to their assigned values (for its own substitutions etc.).  If I could access that map (from inside my `FooExtensionElement.execute()` function) then I could use the value of `abc:foo/@attr1` ("$var1"/"var1") as a key to get the variable's value.  I have been unable to find any lxml documentation of such a map.

**Possible solution 2**:
Use a context-aware (i.e. is aware of current `xsl:` variable and param values and is able to substitute accordingly) xpath evaluation.  To do this - presumably - we need to start with a node in the `xsl` namespace.  In the example above, this could be the previous-sibling to `abc:foo`:

```py
def execute( self, context, self_node, input_node, output_parent ):
    node = self_node.getprevious()
    print( "node tag: {}".format( node.tag ))
    var = deepcopy( node ).xpath( "concat( '', $var1 )" )
    print( "var: {}".format( var ))
```

The output of this is:

```
node tag: {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}variable
```

followed by:

```
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined variable
```

Fail: it's complaining that I haven't provided the value (the one that I'm attempting to find) for `$var1` in the xpath, i.e. it doesn't seem to be aware of current `$variables`.

What I need is access to the current state of XSLT "`$variables`" in the `xsl` namespace: can anyone tell me if this is possible with lxml?

Comment: I'm stumped on how to do what you're specifically asking for, accessing the parameter passed in to the transformer from within the extension's `execute` function. Maybe if you step back and describe what you're trying to accomplish, someone will have an alternate approach?

Comment: Hi @Forensic_07, I've edited my question - hope that is clearer?

Comment: Changed `<abc:foo attr1="$var1"/>` to `<abc:foo attr1="{$var1}"/>` as the curly braces would be the correct way to have the expression evaluated in XSL.  It has no effect on the outcome as originally posted.

Comment: Not the way I wanted, but I did find a workaround.  You can implement the example above `<abc:foo attr1="$var1"/>` as:

    <abc:foo>
      <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
      <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
    </abc:foo>

It's not pretty but it works fine for me.
On the Python/Lxml side, `self_node.get( "attr1" )` should retrieve the _value_ of `$var1`